# Please check my proof that a weird-integral-like $R^2 \to R$ function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $f \in C^0_c(R)$ (continuous function with compact support) and $w \in L^1(R)$ (Lebesgue integrable function) such that $w(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in R$. The running autocorrelation function (it is given by Licklider in [this paper](https://web.mit.edu/HST.723/www/ThemePapers/Pitch/Licklider1951.pdf) p. 133) is the function:

$$\begin{matrix} \phi : & R^2 & \to & R\\
& (t,\tau) & \mapsto & \displaystyle\phi(t,\tau) := \int^\infty_{0} f(t - T)f(t - \tau - T)w(T) \, dT
 \end{matrix} $$

I want to prove that $\phi$ is continuous (therefore it spawns a surface in $R^3$ as Licklider says). This is the sketch of my attempt:

Let $((t_k,\tau_k))$ be a sequence in $R^2$ such that $(t_k,\tau_k)\to (a,b)$ for some $(a,b)\in R^2$, I have to show that the sequence $\phi(t_k,\tau_k) \to \phi(a,b)$ in $R$, that is, I have to show that

\begin{align}
& \phantom{\; \iff \;}\lim_{k\to \infty} \int^\infty_{0}f(t_k - T)f(t_k - \tau_k - T)w(T) \, dT = \int^\infty_{0}f(a - T)f(a - b - T)w(T) \, dT
\end{align}

It is very tempting to move the limit inside the integral and we would have that:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} f(t_k - T)f(t_k-\tau_k - T)w(T) =  f(a - T)f(a - b - T)w(T)$$

since $f$ is continuous and $t_k \to a$ and $\tau_k \to b$, and we would be done. To be sure I can indeed do that I used the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), and defined the sequence $(h_k)$ of functions such that $h_k(T) = f(t_k - T)f(t_k-\tau_k - T)w(T)$, we would have pointwise convergence as: $\lim_{k \to \infty} h_k(T) = h(T)$ where $h(T) := f(a - T)f(a - b - T)w(T)$ for all $T$, however it feels weird to define a sequence such as $h_k(T)$, I don't know if this can be done or if there is a problem with that. Then for the function that dominates every element of the sequence we could take $M$ the maximum of $|f|$ (compact support means it has a maximum) and define $g(T) = M^2w(T)$, we have that $g$ is integrable and it fulfills that $|h_k(T)| \leq g(T)$ for all $h_k$, then we are good to use the theorem and prove the continuity.

¿Is there something wrong with this attempt or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Note that you don't need to change the proof by that much to prove $\phi$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Ok, so I can say even more and prove that it is uniformly continuous (I'll do it :D). Also I suppose you don't see anything wrong with the proof which was my main concern!